# Use of \citet with bibliographystyle unsrt

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

While I use `\citet{Titterington}` and I use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` which all websites say is supposed to produce a citation in the main body like Titterington[1], for me produces a citation in the main body that looks like (author?)[1].

Comment: Maybe this is an option [How to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles (plain, abbrv, unsrt, alpha) as closely as possible with biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo/69706#69706)

Answer (score 10):

replace

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

by

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

Found the solution from here:

http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7950

Answer (score 3):

I did follow [ZYSTEEL's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110775/90454) but my problem was that every `\cite{smith90}` produced a text citation

> Smith et al 1990

in my paper. As I wanted a text citation only when calling `\citet{smith90}`, I found that [declaring `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`](http://merkel.texture.rocks/Latex/natbib.php?lang=en) solved the problem for me. It was suggested in [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17249/90454), but it wasn't clear enough in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using `natbib`. Use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`. If it doesn't help, create a complete example.

Comment: I think it should be `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`.