# Why do I get (author?) when I use \citet with natbib?

Tags: bibtex

I would like to show the author names using `\citet` but I get just the reference number. Here is a minimal code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

 The author \citet{toschi09} has shown that ..

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{foo}

\end{document}
```

And here is foo.bib

```
@article{toschi09,
author = {Toschi, F. and Bodenschatz, E.},
title = {Lagrangian Properties of Particles in Turbulence},
journal = {Annual Review of Fluid Mechanics},
volume = {41},
number = {1},
pages = {375-404},
year = {2009}, 
}
```

What I get is:

> The author (author?) [1] has shown that ..

Any help will be more than welcome, thank you!

Comment: Does switching to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` help?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes Thank you! it works! but what is the file which is created .aux I got a message with regard to it

Comment: The `.aux` file is a temporary file that is created when you compile a document. It contains among other things all the citation commands you used. When you run `bibtex`, it reads this file, finds all those citations,  extracts the corresponding information from the `.bib` file, and generates the bibliography (the `.bbl` file). The next time you run `pdflatex`, this `bbl` file is read, and you get a bibliography.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you a lot for your explanations

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `plain` bibliography style is for numerical references only, while `\citet` only makes sense for author-year citations. Use `natbib`s own version of `plain`, called `plainnat`, instead, and this works fine. I.e. change to

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

This is in fact documented on page 7 of `natbib`s manual:

> The authors can only be listed if the `.bst` file supports author–year
>   citations. The standard .bst files, such as `plain.bst` are numerical
>   only and transfer no author–year information to LaTeX. In this case,
>   `\citet` prints “(author?) [21].”

Comment: Is there some hack that can make this work without changing style? I am forced to use amsplain but I have a lot of citet. I don't want to add author name everywhere manually.

Comment: @ablmf Find-and-replace `\citet` with `\cite`? I don't know `amsplain`, but if it's a numerical style then one wouldn't usually have both author name and number, would one? If you are after both, then I'd suggest asking a new question about it.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a way that preserves numbered ranges, like the `unsrt` bibliography class? I want to use `\citet` to refer to authors in sentences, but still allow for numbered ranges (e.g. [55-63]) for compact citations.

Comment: Answering my own question: see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110775/28304)

Comment: @MRule I suggest you post a new question, I don't know.

Answer (score 19):

I was getting this problem with a custom-generated bibliography style (using Patrick Daly's custom-bib generator, merlin.mbs).  The solution (pointed out to me very helpfully by Patrick) is to generate a style using author-year citations, but use the "numbers" option in the LaTeX document, i.e. in the .dbj file produced by merlin.mbs, uncomment the line

```
ay,%: Author-year
```

and in the .tex file specify

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a way that preserves numbered ranges, like the `unsrt` bibliography class? I want to use `\citet` to refer to authors in sentences, but still allow for numbered ranges (e.g. [55-63]) for compact citations.

Comment: Answering my own question: see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110775/28304)

Answer (score 5):

For those who are also confused by these kinds of problem: Please check there should be not space in the cite command. You should write `\cite{aa,bb,cc}` instead of `\cite{aa, bb, cc}`.

Comment: Thanks, simple and clear answer, which solved my problem quickly. I was difficult to replicate the problem and explain it as the error doesn't tell you much about it.

Answer (score 3):

In case of the [IEEEtran](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) document class, one has to replace

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

by

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was using ```\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}``` which gave the error.

Answer (score 1):

For [Lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lyx) users, remember that in Lyx bibliography settings are configured in two places:

## Document / Settings / Bibliography

Click on `Document` / `Settings` / `Bibliography` to open this configuration dialog:
[image]
Here you can set the citation style format to natbib author year.

## The BibTex bibliography dialog

The first time, click on `Insert` / `List TOC` / `Bib(la)Tex Bibliography` to insert this dialog at the end of your document. For future edit simply click on the BibTex bibliography dialog at the end of your document.

[image]

This is where you should change the style to plainnat [author year] or apalike (author year). This citation key style will then be used by the `\citep{}` and `\citet{}` in your text as well as in the bibliography section.