# LaTeX + BibTeX writes "author?" in front of each citation

Tags: bibtex, citing

I used to write my papers on Windows, with all my citations in a .bib file, which is imported like this:

```
% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{MyBibliography}
```

This all compiled fine. I recently switched to Mac (using TexShop), which produces nearly the same, except that in front of every citation in the text, it writes '**(author?)**'. Like this:

[image]

Other than that, the references, the numbers, and the bibliography itself are exactly the same. This is very irritating. What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: Different encoding of your files?

Comment: Perhaps... How do you check that, and how can one fix it?

Comment: It seems like something is redefining how unresolved references look like. Double check the key you are calling using `\cite` and the key that is given in the `bib`-database. If that's not it, please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: Does this help? [Why do I get (author?) when I use \citet with natbib?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166843)