# Citing does not work

Tags: bibtex, citing

As posted in my other question, I am publishing a book and these 2 errors are the only errors remaining after weeks of struggling in solving problems.

The following image: [image: output in LaTeX] is produced by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\title{testest}
\author{dennis93muller }
\date{August 2016}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
programs as defined by \citet{DeMaio2009Bike-sharing:Future}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Mendeley.bib}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

The bib.file contains the following:

```
@article{DeMaio2009Bike-sharing:Future,
    title = {{Bike-sharing: History, impacts, models of provision, and future}},
    year = {2009},
    journal = {Journal of Public Transportation},
    author = {DeMaio, Paul},
    number = {4},
    pages = {3},
    volume = {12},
    isbn = {1077-291X}
}
```

The output should be: programs as defined by DeMaio. However this is not the case. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I have also tried \cite or \citep, neither have the right ouput!

Comment: +1 for struggling with all the other problems. Maybe you could have saved some time by asking here when stuck.

Comment: if you make a document with just that citation (and minimum number of packages to define \citet etc) referencing your bib file, does it work? if not post it here, if it does, add packages from your main document until it breaks....

Comment: It does not work. \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{testest}
\author{dennis93muller }
\date{August 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

programs as defined by \citet{DeMaio2009Bike-sharing:Future}.

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
provides the same output with the following error: You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suggest to mark this thread as a duplicate of [Why do I get (author?) when I use \citet with natbib?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166840/110998), but don't know how to do it ...

Comment: @gernot there should be a close link just below the question, select that then select duplicate. (it normally takes 5 votes but if you do it the "community" bot will probably step in and close the question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Haven't got enough reputation for closing.

Comment: @gernot oh sorry I thought you could always close your own, perhaps not:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe one can always close ones own post, but it was not mine.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` command in your minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\title{testest} 
\author{dennis93muller} 
\date{August 2016} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
programs as defined by \citet{DeMaio2009Bike-sharing:Future}. 

\section{Introduction}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

You get the output from your graphic when you use a `natbib` incompatible bibliographystyle like e.g. plain. Change it to `plainnat`.

Comment: Truely that is a life saver, thank you so much!