# Reference Citation with name instead of number

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am writing this reference in my `.tex` file

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{Thomas} Thomas, V. A., El-Hajjar, M.,  Hanzo, L.: Performance improvement and cost reduction techniques for radio over fiber communications.IEEE Communications Surveys \& Tutorials. {\boldm $17$}(2), 627-670(2015).
```

When I see the generated file it comes like this:

> expected to form the mainstay of the future fifth generation of wireless
>   networks [1]

instead of `[1]` I need `(Thomas)`.

Comment: Does it helps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166840/why-do-i-get-author-when-i-use-citet-with-natbib?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References

Answer (score 0):

I just run over similar situation. If your reference is just Thomas (also works with spaces, but unfortunately not with commas (yet)), you could define the bibliography with:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
```

(see https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_citation_styles)

Then your bibitem should look like that:

```
\bibitem[Thomas]{Thomas} Thomas, V. A., El-Hajjar, M.,  Hanzo, L.: Performance improvement and cost reduction techniques for radio over fiber communications.IEEE Communications Surveys \& Tutorials. {\boldm $17$}(2), 627-670(2015).
```