# Fix natbib error (authors?) without using predefined bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, bst

I would like to use the `natbib` command `\citet` with a custom `.bst` file.
But the `pdf` file contains "(authors?)" instead (see [Why do I get (author?) when I use \citet with natbib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166840)).

How can I fix this without using predefined `natbib` style (like plainnat)?

I remarked that the `aux` file contains a `bibcite` command that looks like this : `\bibcite{foo2008}{{Foo~2008}{}{{}}{{}}}`. If I manually edit this command I can easily obtain a similar result as when using predefined `natbib` style.

What is responsible for generating the `bibcite` command? How to include more information?
Is it a function from the `bst` style file?

I would like to edit my `bst` file only. Here are my files:

```
%
% Style de bibliographie pour the`se - d'apres alpha.bst
%
% Matthieu Herrb (matthieu@laas.fr) - Juillet 89, Octobre 90
%
%        Les references seront designees tant dans le texte que dans
% la liste recapitulative (ordonnee suivant l'ordre alphabetique du nom
% du premier auteur), par le nom du premier auteur suivi des deux
% derniers chiffres de l'annee de publication, le tout entre crochets.
% Si deux references du meme auteur se rapportent a la meme annee, elles
% seront differenciees par des lettres minuscules (a, b, etc.)
%
 
    % version 0.99a for BibTeX versions 0.99a or later, LaTeX version 2.09.
    % Copyright (C) 1985, all rights reserved.
    % Copying of this file is authorized only if either
    % (1) you make absolutely no changes to your copy, including name, or
    % (2) if you do make changes, you name it something other than
    % btxbst.doc, plain.bst, unsrt.bst, alpha.bst, and abbrv.bst.
    % This restriction helps ensure that all standard styles are identical.
 
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label }
 
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
 
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
 
STRINGS { s t }
 
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
    { add.period$ write$
      newline$
      "\newblock " write$
    }
    { output.state before.all =
        'write$
        { add.period$ " " * write$ }
      if$
    }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
 
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
  label write$
  "]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
 
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}
 
FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {scapify}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\sc " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {underline}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\ul " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
 
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }
 
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{~jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "" * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." emphasize * }
        { " \iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{and}{et} " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
    { ", \iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{editors}{editeurs}" * }
    { ", \iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{editor}{editeur}" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
    { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
        { "--" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
        {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
        { "-" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
          while$
        }
      if$
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ *
      t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    }
      if$
    }
  while$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
    { "" }
    { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
      month
    }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
    'year
    { month " " * year * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title emphasize
}
 
FUNCTION {format.utitle}
{ title emphasize
}
 
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}
 
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
    'skip$
    { " of " * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
    { series field.or.null }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        { "\iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{number}{num\'ero}" }
        { "\iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{Number}{Nume\'ero}" }
      if$
      number tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
        { " \iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{in}{de} " * series * }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
    { edition "l" change.case$ " \iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{edition}{\'edition}" * }
    { edition "t" change.case$ " \iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{edition}{\'edition}" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
 
INTEGERS { multiresult }
 
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
    { #1 'multiresult := }
    { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}
 
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
    { "pages" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
    { "page" pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
 
 
FUNCTION {format.volume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "vol.~" volume * }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.number}
{ number empty$
    { "" }
    { "no.~" number * }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
    { "\iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{chapter}{chapitre}" }
    { type "l" change.case$ }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
    'skip$
    { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
    { "\iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{In}{Dans} " booktitle * }
    { "\iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{In}{Dans} " format.editors * ", " * booktitle * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
  key empty$ not and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { "\iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{Technical Report}{Rapport technique}" }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "t" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ key empty$
    { journal empty$
    { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref *
      warning$
      ""
    }
    { "In {\em " journal * "\/}" * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " key * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
 
FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
    'skip$
    { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " \& " * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      "In "
    }
    { "Volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      " of " *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
    { series empty$
        { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
          crossref * warning$
          "" *
        }
        { "{\em " * series * "\/}" * }
      if$
    }
    { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
 
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{ editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { booktitle empty$
        { key empty$
        { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
          crossref * warning$
          ""
        }
        { "\iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{In}{Dans} " key * }
      if$
    }
    { "\iftoggle{ThesisInEnglish}{In}{Dans} " booktitle * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
 
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.utitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal "journal" output.check
      format.volume output
      format.number output 
      format.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  howpublished address new.block.checkb
  howpublished output
  address output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.utitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.utitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      address empty$
    { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
      organization output
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      new.sentence
      organization output
      publisher output
    }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }
 
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output.nonnull
      address output
    }
      if$
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.utitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
    { address new.block.checka
      address output
    }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
    { organization address new.block.checkb
      organization output
      address output
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  "Master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.utitle output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
 
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { organization output }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  address empty$
    { editor empty$
    { publisher new.sentence.checka }
    { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
      organization output
    }
      if$
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      new.sentence
      editor empty$
    'skip$
    { organization output }
      if$
      publisher output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.utitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  format.date output
  fin.entry
}
 
FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
 
MACRO {jan} {"\monthname[1]"}
 
MACRO {feb} {"\monthname[2]"}
 
MACRO {mar} {"\monthname[3]"}
 
MACRO {apr} {"\monthname[4]"}
 
MACRO {may} {"\monthname[5]"}
 
MACRO {jun} {"\monthname[6]"}
 
MACRO {jul} {"\monthname[7]"}
 
MACRO {aug} {"\monthname[8]"}
 
MACRO {sep} {"\monthname[9]"}
 
MACRO {oct} {"\monthname[10]"}
 
MACRO {nov} {"\monthname[11]"}
 
MACRO {dec} {"\monthname[12]"}
 
MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}
 
MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}
 
MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}
 
MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}
 
MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}
 
MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}
 
MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}
 
MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}
 
MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}
 
MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}
 
MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}
 
MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}
 
MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}
 
MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}
 
MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}
 
MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}
 
MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}
 
MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}
 
MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}
 
MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}
 
READ
 
FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}
 
INTEGERS { len }
 
FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}
 
INTEGERS { et.al.char.used }
 
FUNCTION {initialize.et.al.char.used}
{ #0 'et.al.char.used :=
}
 
EXECUTE {initialize.et.al.char.used}
 
%
% Cette function produit le label avec le nom du premier auteur
%
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s #1 "{vv }{ll}" format.name$
}
 
FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
    { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
    { key #3 }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        { key }
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {author.key.organization.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
    { organization empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        { "The " #4 organization chop.word #3 text.prefix$ }
      if$
    }
    { key }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {editor.key.organization.label}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
    { organization empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        { "The " #4 organization chop.word #3 text.prefix$ }
      if$
    }
    { key }
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
  if$
}
 
%
% Fonction modifiee pour generer les bons labels
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
    'editor.key.organization.label
    { type$ "manual" =
        'author.key.organization.label
        'author.key.label
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
  duplicate$
  "~" *
  year #-1 #4 substring$ field.or.null purify$ *
  'label :=
  year #-1 #4 substring$ field.or.null purify$ 
  *
  sortify 'sort.label :=
}
 
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { nameptr #1 >
    { "   " * }
    'skip$
      if$
      s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr numnames = t "others" = and
    { "et al" * }
    { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
 
FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}
 
FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
    { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
      ""
    }
    { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {author.organization.sort}
{ author empty$
    { organization empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {editor.organization.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { organization empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  sort.label
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
    'editor.organization.sort
    { type$ "manual" =
        'author.organization.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
  *
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
 
ITERATE {presort}
 
SORT
 
STRINGS { longest.label last.sort.label next.extra }
 
INTEGERS { longest.label.width last.extra.num }
 
FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.sort.label :=
  "" 'next.extra :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
  #0 'last.extra.num :=
}
 
FUNCTION {forward.pass}
{ last.sort.label sort.label =
    { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
      last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=
    }
    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
      "" 'extra.label :=
      sort.label 'last.sort.label :=
    }
  if$
}
 
FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
{ next.extra "b" =
    { "a" 'extra.label := }
    'skip$
  if$
  label extra.label * 'label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label 'next.extra :=
}
 
EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}
 
ITERATE {forward.pass}
 
REVERSE {reverse.pass}
 
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ et.al.char.used
    { "\newcommand{\etalchar}[1]{$^{#1}$}" write$ newline$ }
    'skip$
  if$
  preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
%  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{xxxx}" write$ newline$
}
 
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
 
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
 
ITERATE {call.type$}
 
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
 
EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `.bst` file with `natbib`'s author-year citation module, the `.bst` file needs to pass on the author and year information in a way readable for `natbib`. That is done via the optional argument to `\bibitem`. The comments in `natbib.sty` explain

```
 % This package reimplements the LaTeX \cite command to be used for various
 % citation styles, both author-year and numerical. It accepts BibTeX
 % output intended for many other packages, and therefore acts as a
 % general, all-purpose citation-style interface.
 %
 % With standard numerical .bst files, only numerical citations are
 % possible. With an author-year .bst file, both numerical and
 % author-year citations are possible.
 %
 % If author-year citations are selected, \bibitem must have one of the
 %   following forms:
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)Jones, Baker, and Williams]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al., 1990]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{Jones
 %       et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\astroncite{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citename{Jones et al., }1990]{key}...
 %   \harvarditem[Jones et al.]{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{1990}{key}...
 %
 % This is either to be made up manually, or to be generated by an
 % appropriate .bst file with BibTeX.
```

Your `.bst` file wasn't written with this system in mind (in fact it was written before `natbib` was even a thing), but it isn't too hard to make it cooperate with `natbib`.

As you noted, your `.bst` file generates citation labels of the form

```
\bibitem[<author>~<year>]
```

and with two small changes we can make it generate the `natbib`-compatible

```
\bibitem[<author>(<year>)]
```

Just change

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
    'editor.key.organization.label
    { type$ "manual" =
        'author.key.organization.label
        'author.key.label
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
  duplicate$
  "~" *
  year #-1 #4 substring$ field.or.null purify$ *
  'label :=
  year #-1 #4 substring$ field.or.null purify$ 
  *
  sortify 'sort.label :=
}
```

to

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
    'editor.key.organization.label
    { type$ "manual" =
        'author.key.organization.label
        'author.key.label
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
  duplicate$
  "(" *
  year #-1 #4 substring$ field.or.null purify$ *
  ")" *
  'label :=
  year #-1 #4 substring$ field.or.null purify$ 
  *
  sortify 'sort.label :=
}
```

The actual diff between these functions is just

```
--- oldtdotldot.bst 2020-10-09 16:44:49.017918200 +0200
+++ tdotldot.bst    2020-10-09 16:38:01.070090100 +0200
@@ -1038,8 +1038,9 @@
     }
   if$
   duplicate$
-  "~" *
+  "(" *
   year #-1 #4 substring$ field.or.null purify$ *
+  ")" *
   'label :=
   year #-1 #4 substring$ field.or.null purify$ 
   *
```